# How can I reshape a Pandas DataFrame to show if certain values in a column are present by day?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm writing a script to query a database and return a DataFrame, df, that looks like this:

```
       cost data_source process_date   revenue
0  0.796895           A   2016-10-01  0.133634
1  0.222457           B   2016-10-02  0.111921
2  0.980005           C   2016-10-03  0.353150
3  0.332533           D   2016-10-04  0.686957
4  0.554089           E   2016-10-05  0.798600
```

The objective is to check if a `data_source` from the following Series of `all_data_sources` is missing from the DataFrame, df, shown above:

```
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
4    E
5    F
6    G
dtype: object
```

The script should return a new DataFrame which shows by day (Index) which `all_data_sources`(columns) are missing from the queried df. The closest I've gotten in terms of the format I want is using a pivot table:

```
source_by_date = df.pivot_table(values = "cost", index = "process_date",
                            columns = "data_source",
                            aggfunc = np.mean)
```

Which returns a new df looking like the one I would want but with the wrong values:

```
data_source          A         B         C         D         E
process_date                                                  
2016-10-01    0.796895       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2016-10-02         NaN  0.222457       NaN       NaN       NaN
2016-10-03         NaN       NaN  0.980005       NaN       NaN
2016-10-04         NaN       NaN       NaN  0.332533       NaN
2016-10-05         NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.554089
```

Instead of returning the mean of cost for each data source I want it to return True if the data source is missing and False if it isn't missing (or the other way  around).

It doesn't have to be a pivot table. This is just the closest I have gotten to what I want.

The other problem with my current path is that it will just take into account the `data_sources` actually returned from the query which may not include the complete list from the Series `all_data_sources`.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use [get_dummies()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) method:

```
In [79]: x = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('process_date').data_source)

In [80]: x
Out[80]:
              A  B  C  D  E
process_date
2016-10-01    1  0  0  0  0
2016-10-02    0  1  0  0  0
2016-10-03    0  0  1  0  0
2016-10-04    0  0  0  1  0
2016-10-05    0  0  0  0  1

In [81]: new = pd.DataFrame(columns=all_data_sources.ix[~all_data_sources.isin(df.data_source)].values, index=x.index).fillna(0)

In [82]: pd.concat([x, new], axis=1).astype(bool)
Out[82]:
                  A      B      C      D      E      F      G
process_date
2016-10-01     True  False  False  False  False  False  False
2016-10-02    False   True  False  False  False  False  False
2016-10-03    False  False   True  False  False  False  False
2016-10-04    False  False  False   True  False  False  False
2016-10-05    False  False  False  False   True  False  False
```

Data:

```
In [77]: all_data_sources
Out[77]:
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
4    E
5    F
6    G
dtype: object

In [78]: df
Out[78]:
       cost data_source process_date   revenue
0  0.796895           A   2016-10-01  0.133634
1  0.222457           B   2016-10-02  0.111921
2  0.980005           C   2016-10-03  0.353150
3  0.332533           D   2016-10-04  0.686957
4  0.554089           E   2016-10-05  0.798600
```

Some explanations:

```
In [83]: all_data_sources.ix[~all_data_sources.isin(df.data_source)]
Out[83]:
5    F
6    G
dtype: object

In [84]: pd.DataFrame(columns=all_data_sources.ix[~all_data_sources.isin(df.data_source)].values, index=x.index).fillna(0)
Out[84]:
              F  G
process_date
2016-10-01    0  0
2016-10-02    0  0
2016-10-03    0  0
2016-10-04    0  0
2016-10-05    0  0
```

Comment: Thank you! May I ask what the use of `~` is when indexing? Couldn't find much [Multindex / Advanced Indexing Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced)

Comment: @Franco, you are welcome. `~` is a negation AKA `not` operator. It's described [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-operators)

Answer (score 1):

You can group the `data_source` by date and check for each group if all the keys are in the `data_source` based on which built up a logical Series (this works for python 3 with the dictionary comprehension):

```
import pandas as pd
(df.groupby('process_date')['data_source']
   .apply(lambda g: pd.Series({k: k in g.values for k in all_data_sources}))
   .unstack(level = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very concise :). I didn't even know dict comprehensions existed.